# Inconsistent behaviour with numpy broadcasting while creating array of array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

If I'm trying to execute :

```
a = np.ones((1, 2))
b = np.ones((1, 3))

np.array([a, b], dtype=np.ndarray)
```

I get the following error :

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape (1,)
```

But I'm would like to get :

```
array([array([[1., 1.]]), array([[1., 1., 1.]])], dtype=object)
```

But if I'm executing this :

```
a = np.ones((1, 2))
b = np.ones((2, 4))

np.array([a, b], dtype=np.ndarray)
```

I get the expected results :

```
array([array([[1., 1.]]), array([[1., 1., 1.],
                                 [1., 1., 1.]])], dtype=object)
```

Running on :

numpy==1.21.2
python==3.7.11

Comment: Make a 2 element object dtype array, and assign those 2 arrays to its slots.  `np.array` can't be used directly for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @hpaulh comments, this works:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.ones((1, 2))
b = np.ones((1, 3))

test = np.empty((2,), dtype=np.ndarray)

test[0] = a
test[1] = b
```

returns

```
array([array([[1., 1.]]), array([[1., 1., 1.]])], dtype=object)
```